# Batch file to parse txt to rss

Tags: parsing, batch-file, rss

im trying to make some sort of automated rss updater for a local rtmp server and i thought that the easiest way to do it is to make one or two batch files and let them run every minute via windows Task Scheduler.

This server records flv and mp4 files in a dir and i have embedded jwplayer on that local server.
The playlists of that player are feeded via a rss file and i want them to update automaticly.

The first batchfile was easy

del RssRaw.txt
dir /b > RssRaw.txt

the 2nd is the one that i'm just clueless about and would like to ask help.

i would like it to parse every single line of the RssRaw.txt file and saves it in a rss/xml file in the following format:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">
    <channel>

    <item>
        <title> #1 </title>
        <jwplayer:source file="/assets/#1.1" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <title> #2 </title>
        <jwplayer:source file="/assets/#2.1" />
    </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Where #1 is the just filename and #1.1 the filename with the extention (.flv or .mp4)
And where #2 and #2.1 is the next line/file.

I hope it's possible to auto-generate the  tags based on how many lines there are in the RssRaw.txt

It will be helpfull if i can exclude certain lines/words that are in the batchfile because with this setup it will also list the text and batch files in the RssRaw.txt

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction or even know if this is possible in a batch file? Or possibly has a better solution that this?

( please keep in mind that im trying to make this a local server so thats why i didn't look at webservices).

Answer (score 0):

this reads the files directly from the directory, you don't need the first batch:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "header1=<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">"
SET "header2=    <channel>"
SET "footer1=    </channel>"
SET "footer2=</rss>"

(
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO(!header1!
ECHO(!header2!
ECHO(
ENDLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (*.flv *.mp4) DO (
    ECHO(    ^<item^>
    ECHO(        ^<title^> %%~na ^</title^>
    ECHO(        ^<jwplayer:source file="/assets/%%~nxa" /^>
    ECHO(    ^</item^>
)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO(
ECHO(!footer1!
ECHO(!footer2!
)>outfile.rss
```

Nevertheless if you want to read from file, replace the `FOR` loop code with this:

```
FOR /f %%a IN (RssRaw.txt) DO (
```